# Is there an easier way to find the mode of a multiplication table?

Tags: co.combinatorics

You are given a square N by N multiplication table, such that it has N rows and N columns and N>0. Each value is equal to the column number times the row number. Is there a formula for finding the value that occurs most often in this table? For example, in a 4x4 table, the mode is 4 which occurs 3 times. In a 100x100 table, the modes are 360 and 720 which each occur 18 times.

The only way I can think of doing this is counting the number of factor pairs (A times B) with A and B being less than N, also having (A times B) and (B times A) counting as 2 pairs. But C times C (perfect square) only counting as one.

I plan on coding this so I am going for the most efficient solution without just counting the frequencies.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776447/127263

Comment: https://oeis.org/A057143 and https://oeis.org/A057144 are relevant.

Comment: The conjecture made by Peter Košinár at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776447/#comment1638134_776447 that a solution is always a product of primorials is correct, at least in the weaker form that the minimal solution is a product of primorials: If $n$ is not a product of primorials, than for some primes $p_1<p_2$, $p_2$ divides $n$ to a greater power than $p_1$ does, and switching these exponents will produce a smaller number with the same number of divisors $d$ and at least as many divisors $d$ with $d, n/d\leq N$, i.e. occurring at least as often in the multiplication table.

Comment: @Wojowu this is a very cool MSE question!